# Why is my query not grouping the data by the column specified?

Tags: sql, jupyter-notebook

I'm querying some data in Jupyter and encountering some issues with my query. In particular, it fails to group the data by the column specified. Can anyone help, please?

```
%sql select avg(college_enrollment), community_area_name 
from chicago_pschools 
group by community_area_name
```

> RESULT: Improper use of a string column, host variable, constant, or
>   function "COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME".  SQLSTATE=42907 SQLCODE=-134 [SQL:
>   'select avg(college_enrollment), community_area_name from
>   chicago_pschools group by community_area_name'] (Background on this
>   error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

Comment: which data type is  COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME?

Comment: @scaisEdge varchar

Comment: @scaisEdge it wasn't a varchar, I had to cast that as well and now it works! thanks

Comment: as I suspected   ...